Jpype: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'software'
I am trying to import event-ruler library to Python,
However, I am unable to import the required classes from the library into my code, the classes are not being recognized or imported successfully.
Since I tried several things, but now:
import jpype

jar_files = [
    "/content/event-ruler-1.8.1.jar",
    "/content/fastdoubleparser-2.0.0.jar",
    "/content/jackson-databind-2.18.0.jar",
    "/content/jmh-core-1.37.jar",
    "/content/jmh-generator-annprocess-1.37.jar",
    "/content/jsr305-3.0.2.jar",
    "/content/junit-4.13.2.jar"
]

jvmPath = jpype.getDefaultJVMPath() 

classpath = ":".join(jar_files)

jpype.startJVM(jvmPath, classpath=classpath)

Then trying to Import the library
from software.amazon.event.ruler import Ruler

And getting this error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-11ca43dc03d7> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from software.amazon.event.ruler import ACStep

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'software'

